# How can I perform Django's `syncdb --noinput` with call_command?

Tags: django, django-admin, syncdb

```
>>> from django.core.management import call_command
>>> call_command('syncdb')
```

executes the syncdb management command from within a python script. However, I want to run the equivalent of

```
$ python manage.py syncdb --noinput
```

from within a python shell or script. How can I do that?

The following lines don't work without interrupting me with the question whether I want to create a super user.

```
>>> call_command('syncdb', noinput = True) # asks for input
>>> call_command('syncdb', 'noinput') # raises an exception
```

I use Django 1.3.

Comment: Solved: `call_command('syncdb', interactive = False)`

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772990/programmatically-sync-the-db-in-django)?

Comment: @lbp you shouldn't insert the solution in a comment, but in an answer and then accept it. otherwise this question will be without an accepted answer forever.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
call_command('syncdb', interactive = False)
```

EDIT:

I found the answer in the source code. The source code for all management commands can be found in a python module called `management/commands/(command_name).py`

The python module where the `syncdb` command resides is `django.core.management.commands.syncdb`

To find the source code of the command you can do something like this:

```
(env)$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.core.management.commands import syncdb
>>> syncdb.__file__
'/home/user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.pyc'
>>>
```

Of course, check the contents of syncdb.py, and not syncdb.pyc.

Or looking at the [online source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py#L16), the `syncdb.py` script contains:

```
    make_option('--noinput', action='store_false', dest='interactive', default=True,
        help='Tells Django to NOT prompt the user for input of any kind.'),
```

that tells us that instead of `--noinput` on the command line, we should use `interactive` if we want to automate commands with the `call_command` function.

Comment: Does anyone know why you use `interactive` instead of `noinput`? Is this in the Django docs anywhere?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the documentation on this subject is quite obscure. There is an example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code